# Returning String Arr from Function

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to return a string array from a function to another array and i just cant seem to get it working. Any advice?

the call is :

```
labelTypes() = loadLabelCSV(runningPath)
```

the code :

```
Function loadLabelCSV(runpath As String) As String()

    Dim arr(5, 0) As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim line As String
    Dim lineArr() As String
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(runpath & "\labelTypes.csv", Encoding.Default)

    If System.IO.File.Exists(runpath & "\labelTypes.csv") = False Then
        MsgBox("The label types file is missing please check.", vbCritical)
    End If

    Do
        line = reader.ReadLine
        If line = "" Then Exit Do
        lineArr = Split(reader.ReadLine, ",")
        For y = 0 To 5
            arr(y, x) = lineArr(y)
        Next
        x = x + 1
        ReDim Preserve arr(5, UBound(arr, 2) + 1)
    Loop

    Return arr

End Function
```

Comment: _"cant seem to get it working"_ is an extremely vague description of a problem. What happens/doesn't happen? What _is_ the returned value, and what do you actually want it to be? Are there any errors thrown?

Comment: That is a pretty bad way to parse a CSV - tools like CSVHelper will parse and store the data in a *typed collection*.  Then, set `Option Strict On` to catch conversion errors.    Next, `Redim Preserve` is a relic from the 1990s.  All that code can be replaced with `Return File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToArray().Select(Function(j) j.Split(","c)).ToArray()`

Comment: Disregarding any issues with the function itself, this: `labelTypes() = loadLabelCSV(runningPath)`; should be this: `labelTypes = loadLabelCSV(runningPath)`.